# Pagination in Asp.net MVC 4 / 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, view

I am sending a list of records by using model object to the view
and now i want paging 
but the problem is model object what i am passing is not a pagedlist object.

how to convert simple object to pagedList object

here is my code

```
public ActionResult ApplicantsRecord(int page = 1)
{
    List<ApplicantsRecord> ar = new List<ApplicantsRecord>();
    ApplicantsRecord a = new ApplicantsRecord();
    List<ApplicantsRecordDetailViewModel> apvmlist = 
                                    new List<ApplicantsRecordDetailViewModel>();
    ApplicantsRecordDetailViewModel apvm = new ApplicantsRecordDetailViewModel();
    //ar = db.ApplicantsRecords.ToList();
    var groupedAR = db.ApplicantsRecords
                      .GroupBy(x => x.SessionId)
                      .Select(y => new
                      {
                          SessionId = y.Key,
                          ApplicationsRecords = y.FirstOrDefault(),
                      }).OrderByDescending(x => x.ApplicationsRecords.LoginDate)
                      .ToPagedList(page, 10);

    foreach (var i in groupedAR)
    {
        ar.Add(i.ApplicationsRecords);
    }

    return View(ar);
}
```

Comment: `what i am passing is not a pagedlist object` So why you passing not paged list when you have paged list? Why you copy data from paged list to list and passing that list? Why cant you pass `groupedAR` directly?

Comment: how to pass it this i don't know plz send me the line of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your problem, you probably want to do something like this:

```
var groupedAR = db.ApplicantsRecords.GroupBy(x => x.SessionId)
    .Select(y => new
    {
        SessionId = y.Key,
        ApplicationsRecords = y.FirstOrDefault(),

    }).OrderByDescending(x => x.ApplicationsRecords.LoginDate).Select(i=>i.ApplicationsRecords).ToPagedList(page, 10);

return View(ar);
```

Note `.Select(i=>i.ApplicationsRecords)` in above

---

Or you can do something like this:

```
var groupedAR = db.ApplicantsRecords.GroupBy(x => x.SessionId)
    .Select(y => new
    {
        SessionId = y.Key,
        ApplicationsRecords = y.FirstOrDefault(),

    }).OrderByDescending(x => x.ApplicationsRecords.LoginDate);

foreach (var i in groupedAR)
{
    ar.Add(i.ApplicationsRecords);
}
return View(ar.ToPagedList(page, 10));
```

Note that moved `ToPagedList` in other place

Comment: thanks this worked but what would be the code for this in view

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery DataTables https://datatables.net/ . by default it has a paging

View

```
var oProtocolTable = $('#MyTable').DataTable({
        "ajax": "/Home/ProtocolAjaxHandler",
    });
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult ProtocolAjaxHandler(JQueryDataTableParamModel param)
        {
            var ar = db.ApplicantsRecords.ToList();
            if (ar == null)
                return Json(new
                {
                    data = new List<string>()
                },
                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            return Json(new
            {
                aaData = from emp in riski
                         select new[] { emp.col1, emp.col2 }

            },
            JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `List<ApplicantsRecord>` as the model in your view, use `PagedList.IPagedList<ApplicantsRecord>`:

(*top of ApplicantsRecord.cshtml*)

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<ApplicantsRecord>
```

Then just return your paged list from your controller without copying it into something else:

(*end of ApplicantsRecord() controller action*)

```
return View(groupedAr);
```

Once you do that, you should be able to access your model as you are already using it, but it should now have the paging values that you need:

(*somewhere in ApplicantsRecord.cshtml*)

```
Page @Model.PageNumber of @Model.PageCount
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="@Model.PageNumber" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Webdiyer.MvcPager. MvcPager is a free and open source paging component for ASP.NET MVC, it expose a series of extension methods for using in ASP.NET MVC applications, the implementation was inspired by Scott Guthrie's PagedList idea, it was first published in 2009 and had been steadily improved and updated since then. The latest version 3.0 is one the most powerful ASP.NET MVC paging controls.View online demos at http://en.webdiyer.com/mvcpager/demos/